# Check/uncheck checkbox without using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to toggle the state (check/uncheck) of an input type checkbox without using JavaScript/jQuery i.e. only through HTML and CSS?

Say I want to toggle it on click on a label next to it.

If yes, how can we achieve that?

Comment: I don't think it is possible.  Under what circumstances would you like this toggle to happen?

Comment: with plain html you only need to click it to toggle checked and unchecked state, you do not need javascript for this !. Can you clarify your question cause css is only about styling.

Comment: Functional behaviour like this should be controlled by JavaScript. CSS should be used for presentation rather than controlling functionality. Hacks might exist with CSS but it would go against web semantics which really isn't recommended.

Comment: @andrewhiles: Yes surely, but I just wanted to know the workarounds/hacks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to check/uncheck the input from a `<label>`, set an `id` on the input, and use the label's [`for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Using_the_for_attribute) to connect them.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" />

<label for="chk">Click to check/uncheck</label>
```

Another option is to use the label as a container to the input:

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" /> Click to check/uncheck</label>
```

Comment: Yep, @GCyrillus has specified the second option.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for the question before it was updated!**

Only using a hardcoded attribute `checked`:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

If you want to trigger it from code, it's impossible without JS/jQuery.

Comment: could be a good guess about what the OP really try to ask for ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus, i have answered the question before it was updated. When i answered, the question didn't contain the row "Say I want to toggle it on click on a label next to it". After the question update, Ori Drori already gave a good answer

Comment: @CommercialSuicide: Thanks for the initial question's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

label and input are meant to work together :)

see : https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label

> The caption can be associated with a specific form control:
>
> - Using for attribute [[Example A]](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label#Example_A)
> - By putting the form control inside the label element itself. [[Example B]](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label#Example_B)

```html
<label for="a">toggle state</label><input type="checkbox" id="a"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the documentation links! :)

Answer (score 1):

YES , You Can. Use this code

```
<label for="MyCheckBox">Click Me !</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="MyCheckBox" />
```